# Is there a way to display thymeleaf tags on an angular JS partial?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, thymeleaf

Currently, I have my main page rendered by the thymeleaf resolver server-side, so tags such as

```
<span th:text="#{userId}"></span>
```

works properly. However, when I load a partial page using angular's ng-route and routeProvider like

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/c1000', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/C1000.html'
    });
```

and in my C1000.html, I have a tag such as

```
<span th:text="#{userId}"></span>
```

It does not display. I am assuming it's because the main page is resolved by thymeleaf's resolver while the partial is loaded as an ordinary HTML file. I have implemented internationalization so the text for #{userId} changes language based on the properties file. What I want is for the partial page to also display #{userId} similar to how my main page displays it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i think you have to bind all field with anguler js because seema like you including on run time that why it not load

Comment: in your jquery code using like var userid = [[${userId}]]; this way you can access thymeleaf variable in java script code and after you can use this variable